# Upper bound for interpolation polynomial

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm practising for my exam and here is a problem that I have difficulties to solve:

> For a given sequence of different nodes $\left\{x_k \right\}_{k=0}^{n} \subset [a,b]$, let $\left\{l_k\right\}_{k=0}^n$ denotes Lagrange basis polynomials and $L_nf$ interpolation polynomial for $f\in C([a,b])$ in these nodes. Prove that:
>   $$\|L_nf\|_{\infty, \ [a,b]} \le \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n}\|l_k\|_{\infty, \ [a,b]} \right) \|f\|_{\infty, \ [a,b]}$$

Seems very, very hard. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from $$|L_nf(x)| =|\sum_{k=0}^nf(x_k)l_k(x)| \leq \sum_{k=0}^n|f(x_k)|\,|l_k(x)|.$$

Comment: Can you give a reference, or a sketch of a proof?